# Pass in parameter from ajax success response to Url Action method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ajax call to an Api that adds the data to database, I would like success function to call a controller with action method to different with parameter received from response of API call. How can I do that

Ajax Call

```
 $.ajax({
            //Url should contain the method you want to run
            url: "/api/ApiTest",
            //Method will be one of the REST API verb
            method: "POST",
            //These are all the parameters to be passed to method for rest api
            data:viewModel,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var bookingIDParam = data.Booking.BookingID
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("BookingInfo", "Booking", new { BookingID = bookingIDParam })';
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured!!")
            }
        });
```

I get an error "The name 'bookingIDParam' does not exist in the current context

How can I call different controller/go to a url with action method with parameter from response.

Comment: You can't; at least not how you're trying to. All of the server-side stuff happens before the final page is delivered to the client. The AJAX call happens after that and the AJAX response happens even after that. You're going to have to tweak the URL using javascript. You could just do something like `new { BookingID = "REPLACEME" }` in the razor code and then when you get the AJAX response, replace REPLACEME in the resultant URL with the value from the AJAX response. Take a look at that line in the browser if it's confusing. You'll see `window.location.href = 'some real URL';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting some dummy string to replace it later:

```
var url_redirect = '@Url.Action("BookingInfo", "Booking", new { BookingID = "00replace00" })';

$.ajax({
    ....


      success: function (data) {
                url_redirect = url_redirect.replace("00replace00", data.Booking.BookingID );
                window.location.href =url_redirect ;
            },
```